# I including a recipe multiple times with different attributes

Tags: java, chef-infra

I thought I could install multiple JDKs by doing something like this:

```
node[:mycookbook][:jdk_versions].each do |jdk_version|
  node.set[:java][:jdk_version] = jdk_version
  include_recipe "java::default"
end
```

However, this only installs 1 JDK version: the 1st version in the attribute. I'm  guessing because attributes are determined during compile phase and then the installation of java from the include_recipe just re-runs with the same attribute (and considers itself already up to date).

Any suggestions for re-using a recipe with different attributes set?

** edit **

I just noticed this over here https://docs.chef.io/recipes.html#include-recipes

> If the include_recipe method is used more than once to include a
>   recipe, only the first inclusion is processed and any subsequent
>   inclusions are ignored.

*** edit 2 ***
based on @tensibai suggestion, I am now able to get multiple JDKs installed, using the resources from the java cookbook manually in my own cookbook.

```
arch = node[:java][:arch]

node[:mycookbook][:jdk_versions].each do |jdk_version|
    node.set[:java][:java_home] = "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk#{jdk_version}"
    is_default = jdk_version == node[:mycookbook][:default_jdk_version]

    java_ark "jdk#{jdk_version}" do
      url node[:java][:jdk][jdk_version][arch][:url]
      default is_default
      checksum node[:java][:jdk][jdk_version][arch][:checksum]
      app_home node[:java][:java_home]
      bin_cmds node[:java][:jdk][jdk_version][arch][:bin_cmds]
      alternatives_priority node[:java][:alternatives_priority]
      retries node[:java][:ark_retries]
      retry_delay node[:java][:ark_retry_delay]
      action :install
    done
done
```

After that, I get the following (release version redacted) after the initial chef run:

```
- (dir) jdk1.6.0_X
- (dir) jdk1.7.0_Y
- (dir) jdk1.8.0_Z
- (link) jdk6 -> /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_X
- (link) jdk7 -> /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_Y
- (link) jdk8 -> /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_Z
```

For some reason, JDK8 (which for this run was set to default, so `is_default` resolves to true) gets linked to the jdk 6 path. I also get clone resources warnings relating to set-alternatives during the run. However, if I re-run chef (with same attributes set), it fixes the symlink:

```
  * java_ark[jdk6] action install (up to date)
....
  * java_ark[jdk7] action install[2016-05-04T07:50:37+00:00] WARN: Cloning resource attributes for java_alternatives[set-java-alternatives] from prior resource (CHEF-3694)
....
  * java_ark[jdk8] action install
- Symlink /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_Y to /usr/lib/jvm/jdk8[2016-05-04T07:50:37+00:00] WARN: Cloning resource attributes for java_alternatives[set-java-alternatives] from prior resource (CHEF-3694)
```

Any idea why this would be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [java](https://github.com/agileorbit-cookbooks/java#java_ark) cookbook README:

> This cookbook contains the `java_ark` LWRP. Generally speaking this LWRP
>   is deprecated in favor of `ark` from the [ark cookbook](https://github.com/burtlo/ark#examples), but it is still
>   used in this cookbook for handling the Oracle JDK installation.

And from the [ark] README examples:

```
ark 'jdk' do
   url 'http://download.example.com/jdk-7u2-linux-x64.tar.gz'
   version '7.2'
   path "/usr/local/jvm/"
   home_dir "/usr/local/jvm/default"
   checksum  '89ba5fde0c596db388c3bbd265b63007a9cc3df3a8e6d79a46780c1a39408cb5'
   append_env_path true
   owner 'foobar'
 end
```

You can just make an hask of jdk flavors you wish to install and call ark multiples times with something like:

Attributes (dummy values):

```
default['jdk']['open-1.7'] = {
  "url" => "http://download.example.com/jdk-7u2-linux-x64.tar.gz",
  "version" => "7.2",
  "checksum" => "89ba5fde0c596db388c3bbd265b63007a9cc3df3a8e6d79a46780c1a39408cb5"
}

default['jdk']['open-1.6'] = {
  "url" => "http://download.example.com/jdk-6u42-linux-x64.tar.gz",
  "version" => "6.42",
  "checksum" => "89xxxxxxxxxx08cb5"
}
```

Recipe:

```
node['jdk'].each do |jdk,properties|
  ark jdk do
    url properties['url']
       version properties['version']
       path "/usr/local/jvm/"
       home_dir "/usr/local/jvm/default"
       checksum  propertie['checksum']
       append_env_path true
       owner 'foobar'
  end
end
```

I let you extend the values in hash and within the recipe according to your needs (setting the default jdk, etc).

Comment: Thanks @tensibai,  just what i was looking for. missed the readme there.

Comment: @Brett NP, just that I don't like to steal credits from actual documentation when answering, so I started from it before showcasing how it could be used ;)

Comment: Tensibai, have added more info in the question - the solution provided worked great besides the symlink to app_home.